# Is it possible to use variables to access columns of records in postgresql trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a trigger to update my timestamps for each table. I use the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_timstamp_table0() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
IF NEW IS DISTINCT FROM OLD THEN
  NEW.table0_timestamp_column = extract( 'epoch' from NOW() )
  RETURN NEW;
ELSE
  RETURN NULL;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Since all the timestamp columns have different names i have to write a function for each table.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_timstamp(timestamp_col_name varchar) RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
IF NEW IS DISTINCT FROM OLD THEN
  NEW.(timestamp_col_name) = extract( 'epoch' from NOW() )
  RETURN NEW;
ELSE
  RETURN NULL;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

So i can use the same function for every trigger. But i don't know the right syntax for accessing the column via a variable `NEW.(timestamp_col_name)`.

Is this possible? and how it is done?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question: [How to get the key fields for a table in plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984675/how-to-get-the-key-fields-for-a-table-in-plpgsql-function/)