# Is there a easy way to find number of index of a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, indexing

I have a table called User, it has column uid, age, etc.
First I run \d+ User;
Then I can see it tells me information below:

```
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (uid)
```

So I know uid is used as index.
Then I use

```
SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM User;
```

to get number of indexes.

But is there any better way, for example, I can use pg_class, pg_stats ...

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9985338/1507210

Comment: What do you mean by "number of index"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, [`user` is a reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Don't ever use it as identifier.

By "number of indexes" you probably mean "number of rows".

For counting *all* rows in a table, an [index is only going to be useful, if it is considerably smaller than the table itself](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Is_.22count.28.2A.29.22_much_faster_now.3F) (in Postgres 9.2 with index-only scans).

Your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM tbl;
```

actually counts how many non-null values of `uid` can be found in table `tbl` -  which happens to coincide with the total number of (live) rows for columns without `NULL` values. If you actually want to count rows, use instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl;
```

Slightly shorter and faster.

If an **estimate** based on the last ANALYZE run is good enough, you can query the system catalog:

```
SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'my_schema.my_tbl'::regclass;
```

Obviously much faster, since only a single row has to be read.
Refer to the [Postgres Wiki about counting](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting) for ways to count rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of indexes on a table from the catalog:

```
SELECT c2.relname, i.indisprimary, i.indisunique, i.indisclustered, i.indisvalid, pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid, 0, true),
  pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid, true), contype, condeferrable, condeferred, c2.reltablespace
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_class c2, pg_catalog.pg_index i
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint con ON (conrelid = i.indrelid AND conindid = i.indexrelid AND contype IN ('p','u','x'))
WHERE c.oid = 'tablename'::regclass AND c.oid = i.indrelid AND i.indexrelid = c2.oid
ORDER BY i.indisprimary DESC, i.indisunique DESC, c2.relname;
```

Simply replace the select part with an appropriate count statement to get the number.

(Note: to make psql show this kind of query, run it as `psql -E`.)